# More common functional syntax pattern

Tags: python, filter, functional-programming

In python I'm familiar with the functional syntax of something like:

```
data = [{'Age': 10, 'Name': 'Greg'}, {'Age': 20, 'Name': 'Sarah'}]
filter(lambda item: item['Name'] == 'Greg', data)
```

And for [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) it uses the (approximate) syntax of:

```
filter(condition, element_list)
```

What is the most common functional syntax for this? using the above, or flipping it so that the `element_list` or `iterable` comes first? Why would one method be preferred over the other?

Comment: Python is a terrible language for learning these combinators. GVR is on record as saying he hates the paradigm and tried to avoid putting `map` / `filter` in the core library (and was happy `reduce`, an equally useful stream combinator, was relegated to the never-used `functools` module). You'll likely want to either learn an actual functional language (Haskell or OCaml, for instance) or go with something like Python or Rust that implements the stream combinators in a less awkward way.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo sure -- could you show an example of how one of those would do `map` / `filter` ?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo also you say Python is terrible but then that I may want to use it -- or was there a typo on one of those?

Comment: Oh, oops! I meant Ruby (which is very much like Python but does this particular thing much better) or Rust (which practically reinvents most of modern OOP from the ground up with a more modern functional approach)

Comment: As for syntax, Frank basically beat me to it. In most OOP-ish languages, you want `map` / `filter` to be *methods*, not standalone functions. In pure functional languages, they make sense as functions because function composition is cheap. But to make them standalone functions in Python is to relegate them as an inferior alternative to list comprehensions forever in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, Swift, and even JavaScript, `map` and `filter` are methods on lists.  You would write

Swift, for example, would have you write:

```
myList.filter { item in item["name"] == "Greg" }
```

Java would have you turn your array into a stream, and then various map and filter operations are applied to the stream:

```
myList.stream().forEach(item -> print(item))
```

[My syntax may be slightly off.]

Comment: can Swift be used outside an iphone app?